# How to remove the scientific notation from matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have trouble removing the scientific notation from the y axis on my matplotlib chart. (I want to display the original str or float held in the variable, If I use plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)) I get an attribute arror: 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'yaxis'.
Also tired plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain'), that did nothing. (no error either)

```
from binance.client import Client
import time, os, csv, datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

client = Client(apikey, apisecret)

mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['ytick.right'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelright'] = True
plt.rcParams['ytick.left'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelleft'] = False

x_vars = []
y_vars = []

def animate(i):
    global x_vars
    global y_vars
    if len(x_vars) > 30:
        x_vars = x_vars[-30:] 
        y_vars = y_vars[-30:] 
    else:
        pass

    current_time = client.get_server_time()
    current_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="XRPBTC")

    trstime = current_time["serverTime"] / 1000
    time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(trstime)).strftime('%M:%S')

    x_vars.append(str(time))
    y_vars.append(float(current_price["price"]))

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vars, y_vars)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)  


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))`? The yaxis attribute refers to the axis object, whereas plt is more equivalent to the figure object; gca stands for "get current axis".

Comment: Thanks, error doesn't show up anymore but I still get the scientific notation. :(

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it is working now, just had to insert plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', useOffset=False, axis='y') inside the animate function.

Comment: good call - annoying preset